# Time Sensitive Collaborative Filtering

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to use collaborative filtering to recommend items to the user based on their past purchase. I have created a user vector representing his usage and item vector(A) with values populated as probabilty of B given A. The objective to somewhat capture the items sold together in items vector representation. Now I need to find the time when these recommendations should be presented. As the items I am recommending are of periodic use timing is very important.

So I am trying to explore constraint-based Recommendations to make my recommendation time sensitive. The approach I am thinking is to create time-sensitive constraint based on the last date of purchase and average consumption rate. But the problem is creating constraint as user level will become computationally difficult.

I need your suggestion regarding the approach or suggestion of any better way to implement the same. All I want to develop a recommendation engine using customer's usage data of items that are consumed and required to purchase again. I need to output list of recommendation as well as timing of presenting the recommendation to the user

Thanks

Comment: This question isn't directly about python. But about generic algorithmic and machine learning, might need to be mooved to (https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are two basic options here that you can pursue.  On the one hand, the temporal features can be incorporated as additional information and converted into a kind of hybrid recommendation. The Python package "lightfm" is a good example. 
On the other hand, the problem can also be modeled as a time series problem. A well-known paper dealing with Next Basket Recommendations is "A Dynamic Recurrent Model for Next Basket Recommendation". Here too, there are already implementations on Github.